# Issue with scheduled refreshes on Tableau Server: invalid data type error

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I have a dashboard that uses a join of a spatial file (MapInfo tab file) and data from a custom SQL query. Basically, the spatial file provides market areas, and the query, the values. The join is based on full outer join on the market name. On Tableau Desktop it works fine. I can refresh, filter, and whatever else I need, but, when I send it to the Tableau server and schedule a daily refresh, it always fails with the following messages:

• As a PDS: Unknown Failure ( status code = 1003, [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid SQL data type )

• As an "Embed on the workbook": Connectionless Failure ( status code = 10000, [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid SQL data type )

I've tried different troubleshoots like checking username/pass, data types, data volume, and query performance. No matter what I do, it always fails to refresh. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Marcus

Comment: What specifically are trying to refresh, just the SQL query? Have you tried your query as a view and connecting to that as an extract and then embedding the creds in the workbook?

Comment: General rule - to diagnose a problem, simplify with extreme focus to isolate the issue. For example, keep trimming things out of your data source and then testing the refresh, remove the spatial file, remove the join, then keep removing things from your SQL. Get rid of everything extraneous - so work with a test copy and have workbook that only displays something simple like the COUNT(table). When you remove one specific aspect and the error goes away, and then add back just that aspect and the error recurs, then you’ve isolated the issue and can then diagnose and choose alternate approaches

Comment: ALso, check the logs and don’t use custom SQL unless you really need to (it’s often unnecessary) better for many reasons to define relationships between tables in Tableau and let it generate the SQL. Often people use custom SQL just because they are used to it.

Comment: One other avenue to pursue, you might have different drivers installed on your server than on desktop—or different versions of the drivers

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Looks like Tableau can't process automatic refreshes if the data source has a join spatial file.